# Get a notification when a window is set as active

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, keylogger

I'm trying to write a basic keylogger in C++ and so far I managed to install a low lever keyboard hook using the win api. It notifies me everytime a key is pressed.
I would like to do something similar to notify me every time the focus is changed to another window, so I know which window the user is typing in.
I tryed to set a HW_CBT hook but it doesn't give me any notifications.

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT:

I have edded this code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    cout<<"event";
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, NULL, NULL);`

I also have this in my program:

```
while(true)
  GetMessage(&msg,0,WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST);
```

I'm still not getting any notifications when I run the program, except for the ones about key strokes.

EDIT 2!!
I got it done using `GetWindowText()`, `GetForegroundWindow()` and a timer. Not really what I was looking for but this will do. 
I'll just accept the first answer...

Comment: Just deleted my answer recommending SetWindowsHookEx(), noticed you'd tried a WH_CBT hook. Try a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook instead to monitor all messages.

Comment: tryid that.. still ain't getting any notifications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could be useful to you? [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Installs a hook procedure that monitors messages before the system sends them to the destination window procedure

Comment: I used that to get keyboard events. But what type of hook should I install to get notifications when the active window changes? I tryied a cbt hook but I don't get any notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WH_CALLWNDPROC or WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hook to get WM_ACTIVATE (notifications for both window activation and de-activation) messages sent to your hook before or after they are sent to actual window's window procedure.